# Is there a way to get the Node/Element/HTMLElement from JSX before it's mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is it possible to get the element object from JSX before it's mounted?

In the following code for example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
const container = <div id='something'>My simple div</div>;
const element = container.??? // Get Node/Element/HTMLElement from 'container'.
```

I know there is a [ref attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) but this method doesn't seem to work. Also, I find it a bit cumbersome compared to something that's inline.

```
let element = null;
const container = <div id='something' ref={(containerElement) => {element = containerElement;}} />;
```

This probably doesn't work because the component isn't mounted yet (which is the use-case I'm looking for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real DOM element appears when the virtual React element is rendered, so you need to render `container` first and then use either [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```js
const container = <div ref={_element => element = _element}>My simple div</div>;
let element;

ReactDOM.render(container, document.body);
alert(element);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Or a DOM query:

```js
const container = <div id="something">My simple div</div>;

ReactDOM.render(container, document.body);
const element = document.querySelector('#something');
alert(element);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```